# DataURI is getting as null in Controller? How to pass DataUrl to java controller from javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, ajax

I am using the following to pass parameter from javascript to Java Controller. The following allows to pass the data if only Name is available, but if i added DataURI both data is passed to contoller as null.

```
$.post("/captureImage",{DataURI:strdataURL,Name:'${user}'}, function (data) { 
alert(data);
}
```

Comment: `dataURI` vs `DataURI` ?

Comment: I meant DataURI. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the code below.

```
 var passdata= {"uridata" : dataUrl,"Name" :'${user}'}
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType : 'json',
    url: "/captureImage",
    data: JSON.stringify(passdata),
    error: function (result)
    {
       //do something
},
    success :function(result) 
{
       // do what ever you want with data

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide little explanation why my code doesn't work?